# PyQT4 change qDateTimeEdit time value?

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt4

got stuck on this part of my program.. and it seems i cant find a decent
example of how to do this..

i got a QDateTimeEdit object 
i already set its displaying value to what my current system time is using

```
self.ui.dateTimeEdit.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
```

its output is for example is **7/16/2012 12:00:00 AM**

Now my problem is..
i want to set **12:00:00 AM** to **11:59:59 PM**

how can i do this please?

thanks to anyone willing to spend time on my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are basically three different objects you can use in PyQt:

- QDate
- QTime
- QDateTime

The QDateTime accepts the other two types. So you can define the date of a QDateTime Object using a QDate instance and the same can be done with QTime.

Obviously, if you're trying to change the time you need to use a QTime object.

Here are some examples:

```
#create a QDateTimeEdit object
myDTE = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit()

#get current date and time
now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()

#set current date and time to the object
myDTE.setDateTime(now)

#set date only
today = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
myDTE.setDate(today)

#set time only
this_moment = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
myDTE.setTime(this_moment)

#set an arbitrary date
some_date = QtCore.QDate(2011,4,22) #Year, Month, Day
myDTE.setDate(some_date)

#set an arbitrary time
some_time = QtCore.QTime(16,33,15) #Hours, Minutes, Seconds (Only H and M required)
myDTE.setTime(some_time)

#set an arbitrary date and time
someDT = QtCore.QDateTime(2011,4,22,16,33,15)
myDTE.setDateTime(someDT)
```

Comment: Thanks alot dex19dt!. this sample is really good, and better for people in my level.