# PyQt4: Printing OS Date/Time to a label

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to learn Python and PyQt4 GUIs. I'd like to print the date/time from the OS to my main window on a label. I understand there's a DateTimeEdit widget that lets users see (but also edit -- which I don't want) the time, as is the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498998/pyqt4-change-qdatetimeedit-time-value). I want to always just print it straight from the OS. My research has found the QDateTime object but the documentation doesn't indicate they emit any kind of signals which would be useful after a regular amount of time has ticked. So I'm guessing that I have to poll it, which will require multithreading if I don't want it to block. Is there a more elegant way of doing this or is the way I'm thinking of doing it the only way?

(I realize users can just look at the taskbar but I need to provide some feedback that the program is running on the proper time)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MyWin(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('time', self)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
        self.timer.start()

    def displayTime(self):
        self.label.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWin()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1. If you only need to display date\time, simple `QLabel` will suffice.
2. `QTimer` is your friend, if you need to do something periodically. No need to deal with threads - signal\slot system handles that. Connect `QTimer.timeout()` signal to any callable, set interval, call `start()` - and that's it.